# Data frame and the very common mistake while using character columns

Tags: r, character, dataframe

A very unexpected behavior of the useful `data.frame` in R arises from keeping `character` columns as factor. This causes many problems if it is not considered. For example suppose the following code:

```
foo=data.frame(name=c("c","a"),value=1:2)
#   name val
# 1    c   1
# 2    a   2

bar=matrix(1:6,nrow=3)
rownames(bar)=c("a","b","c")
#   [,1] [,2]
# a    1    4
# b    2    5
# c    3    6
```

Then what do you expect of running `bar[foo$name,]`? It normally should return the rows of `bar` that are named according to the `foo$name` that means rows 'c' and 'a'. But the result is different:

```
bar[foo$name,]
#   [,1] [,2]
# b    2    5
# a    1    4
```

The reason is here: `foo$name` is not a character vector, but an integer vector.

```
foo$name
# [1] c a
# Levels: a c
```

To have the expected behavior, I manually convert it to character vector:

```
foo$name = as.character(foo$name)
bar[foo$name,]
#   [,1] [,2]
# c    3    6
# a    1    4
```

But the problem is that we may easily miss to perform this, and have hidden bugs in our codes. Is there any better solution?

Comment: How is documented behavior a bug?  `?data.frame` tells you how to change this globally, but changing it is likely to break other people's code and cause you more issues.  Further, `?data.frame` has an example of how to prevent it from automatically converting character vectors to factor by using `I()`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich You are right. I corrected the title. By bug I mean our bug, not R!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich So would you please write your I() method as an answer?

Comment: No, I'm not sure it's better. I don't have a lot of knowledge about the `AsIs` class.

Comment: This has frustrated me to the point where I believe there should be a 'paste0' like function for data.frame()...and read.table()/csv/whatever...and cbind()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature and R is working as documented. This can be dealt with generally in a few ways:

1. use the argument `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in the call to `data.frame()`. See `?data.frame`
2. if you detest this behaviour so, set the option globally via

   ```
   options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   ```
3. (as noted by @JoshuaUlrich in comments) a third option is to wrap character variables in `I(....)`. This alters the class of the object being assigned to the data frame component to  include `"AsIs"`. In general this shouldn't be a problem as the object inherits (in this case) the class `"character"` so should work as before.

You can check what the default for `stringsAsFactors` is on the currently running R process via:

```
> default.stringsAsFactors()
[1] TRUE
```

The issue is slightly wider than `data.frame()` in scope as this also affects `read.table()`. In that function, as well as the two options above, you can also tell R what all the classes of the variables are via argument `colClasses` and R will respect that, e.g.

```
> tmp <- read.table(text = '"Var1","Var2"
+ "A","B"
+ "C","C"
+ "B","D"', header = TRUE, colClasses = rep("character", 2), sep = ",")
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: chr  "A" "C" "B"
 $ Var2: chr  "B" "C" "D"
```

Comment: If you adopt the approach of a global change in this behavior, be sure to include a warning in _all_ your postings to SO to that effect. Your observed results will be different than those of us who have been tempted to do so but have resisted.

Comment: Any idea if wrapping character vectors in `I()` is useful?  E.g. `data.frame(name=I(c("c","a")),value=1:2)`.

Comment: @DWin was that directed at me? But its a good point, you wind up with significantly different answers when you change that globally.  However, I still do it.

Comment: @Justin: It was a general "you". Think of it as a personal triple-dot construction. If you match that description, behave accordingly.  Terry Therneau says Mayo Clinic has set up their programming shop so that is the default. I'm not saying it is wrong, quite the opposite in fact, just that it _is_ non-standard.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Good point: I have added this as a third option with attribution of course. I have mainly come across this in the data objects for the **pls** package which uses it to embed a matrix as a component of a data frame, which caused me some confusion at the time. For characters in data frames I don't see a problem; this is a documented use-case for `I()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example data below, author and title are automatically converted to factor (unless you add the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you are creating the data). What if we forgot to change the default setting and don't want to set the options globally?

Some code I found somewhere (most likely SO) uses `sapply()` to identify factors and convert them to strings.

```
dat = data.frame(title = c("title1", "title2", "title3"),
                 author = c("author1", "author2", "author3"),
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 1))
# > str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ title     : Factor w/ 3 levels "title1","title2",..: 1 2 3
#   $ author    : Factor w/ 3 levels "author1","author2",..: 1 2 3
#   $ customerID: num  1 2 1

dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)] = lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)], 
                                 as.character)
# > str(dat)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ title     : chr  "title1" "title2" "title3"
#   $ author    : chr  "author1" "author2" "author3"
#   $ customerID: num  1 2 1
```

I *assume* this would be faster than re-reading in the dataset with the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument, but have never tested.